# Is there a way to make my Ubuntu PC sleep and wake up at certain times all the time?

Tags: bash, suspend, 22.04, hibernate

I basically want to have my PC sleep and also wake up at a specified time **all the time forever**. With research, I did find out about `rtcwake` but as far as I know it's basically a one time use that I would have to manually do everyday. I'm just looking for something that works automatically, and I just do not know how I can use bash to force the rtcwake command if that makes any sense at all.

In addition to wanting automatic sleep, I also have this issue of rtcwake not working anyway when using the "disk" option, as it throws the error:

```
 rtcwake: unrecognised suspend state 'disk'
```

Comment: I don't think, that waking a computer from a software inside a hard disk is possible. It is possible to set a wake-up time from BIOS and UEFI menus, but it (probably) only allow once a day. If you need to wake the computer multiple times a day, you should use something externally. For my home lab, I have a raspberry pi 0 always on an connected to the internet. Using `etherwake` I send wake on lan commands to my server and desktop computer when needed.

Comment: Please do not just show the error; also include the actual command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To suspend/hiberbate you can use

```
systemctl suspend
systemctl hibernate
```

Put it in `/etc/crontab` with a time you want this to happen.

```
1 0 * * * root /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
```

---

For waking up a system you can use `rtcwake`. An example waking a system up at 4  pm/16:00:

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t "$(date -d 'today 16:00:00' '+\%s')"
```

You can also put this in `/etc/crontab` using `@reboot` as a trigger.

```
@reboot root /usr/bin/rtcwake -m no -l -t "$(/usr/bin/date -d 'today 16:00:00' '+\%s')"
```

---

You can combine the two and that would be:

```
0 23 * * *  root /usr/bin/rtcwake -m disk -s 60*60*12
```

so at 23:00 it will suspend and wake up 60 * 60 * 12 seconds (12 hours) later.

Mind that there is a possible conflict: if the system is busy doing something it will stop that and continue with suspending.  There are also tools that do not suspend if there is activity, like [autosuspend](https://autosuspend.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.0/) `sudo apt install autosuspend`.

Comment: Definitely learnt a lot from this, thank you so much! However it seems for my one I had to do sudo rather than root, is this depending on the distro I am using or is root also supposed to work?

Comment: @Jo-El as of today I can reboot my notebook using a galaxy smartwatch :D That could work too for you but you need to be in "range" of your system (ie. 5 mtr for BT and in the same network for wifi or if possible to add a sim card to your machine using your phone ;-) )

Comment: Oh and thanks for the accepted vote :D You have the honor of giving me the reputation to pass Oli as the #1 on AU.

Comment: Haha I'm glad I made your day man, it's well deserved.

Comment: And that is an amazing project that you completed there man congratulations, I'm going to add this to my future project list

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, I hope all is well. I am still very grateful for the assistance you provided me regarding the system wake up.
Now that I have some free time, I was interested in that little project you did, are you able to provide a tutorial/pointer as to how you did it? Did you run a code on the smartwatch to do this? is this some inbuilt feature? Can you do this with other smartwatches? Really interested

Comment: this is what you need on your phone: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1 and you need to install the desktop version, It is pretty straight forward :) This is a good start: https://kdeconnect.kde.org/